# How to make sure this text input value works without javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, logic

OK, So I am making a search box that has a value that goes away on click and comes back if you click away from the search box. Like the stackoverflow search but If you click off the search, the value comes back. I hope I'm being clear ( I know very little about javascript )... But For the users that don't have javascript enabled, how do I just make it a blank input? Here's my code

`<INPUT type="text" name="q" value="Search using Business Name or Category..." onFocus="if(this.value == 'Search using Business Name or Category...') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search using Business Name or Category...';}" />`

I thought that maybe I should do a php if javascript enabled but I looked and couldnt find any php scripts? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`placeholder`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute) attribute, please!

```
<INPUT type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search using Business Name or Category..." value="" />
```

Then use [**feature detection**](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html) with JavaScript to make the placeholder work for browsers without support for the placeholder attribute.

For example, using Moderlizr with jQuery (untested):

```
// Add placeholder support for browsers which don't support it.
// TODO Special styling.
if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
    $('input[placeholder][value=]')
        .each(function () {
            var $this = this;

            $this.val($this.attr('placeholder'));
        })
        .focus(function () {
            var $this = this;

            if ($this.val() === $this.attr('placeholder')) {
                $this.val('');
            }
        })
        .blur(function () {
            var $this = this;

            if ($this.val() === '') {
                $this.val($this.attr('placeholder'));
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I was not even aware of this attribute! (+1)

Comment: Close - you need to separate `$('input[placeholder][value=]').each(...)` and `$('input[placeholder]').focus(...).blur(...)`, so that the behaviour is properly set even on those fields which have default values...

Comment: @Stobor, I explicitly omitted handling textboxes with a default value for simplicity's sake.  On the other hand, with a split solution `$.fn.live` could be used which could be more efficient and clean from a DOM perspective.  Users can tweak my solution to their needs; I was only offering an example of how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Set the initial value with JavaScript (this assumes you have an ID):

```
// Somewhere near the bottom of your document
document.getElementById("q").value = "Search...";
```

Personally I lean towards using a separate element floating on top of the input for stuff like this though, as I think modifying the value for this is a dirty trick.